# Justify text inside Android Textview

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable, text-justify

I want to Justify text inside Android TextView. With copy and share function and can accept spannable string. Can someone help me. It's so important for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368339/justifying-text-inside-a-textview-in-android

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution for the text-justify in Android.
I have created a Custom Textview class, with this you can solve the justification issue in Android.

```
   <com.trailcreator.util.JustifyCustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/yourTextViewID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the class

```
public class JustifyCustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

//Object that helps us to measure the words and characters like spaces.
private Paint mPaint;

//Thin space (Hair Space actually) character that will fill the spaces
private String mThinSpace = "\u200A";

//String that will storage the text with the inserted spaces
private String mJustifiedText = "";

//Float that represents the actual width of a sentence
private float mSentenceWidth = 0;

//Integer that counts the spaces needed to fill the line being processed
private int mWhiteSpacesNeeded = 0;

//Integer that counts the actual amount of words in the sentence
private int mWordsInThisSentence = 0;

//ArrayList of Strings that will contain the words of the sentence being processed
private ArrayList<String> mTemporalLine = new ArrayList<String>();

//StringBuilder that will hold the temporal chunk of the string to calculate word index.
private StringBuilder mStringBuilderCSequence = new StringBuilder();

//List of SpanHolder class that will hold the spans within the giving string.
private List<SpanHolder> mSpanHolderList = new ArrayList<>();

//StringBuilder that will store temp data for joining sentence.
private StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder();

private int mViewWidth;

private float mThinSpaceWidth;

private float mWhiteSpaceWidth;

//Default Constructors!
public JustifyCustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public JustifyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public JustifyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if (mJustifiedText.replace(" ", "")
            .replace("", mThinSpace)
            .equals(this.getText().toString().replace(" ", "").replace("", mThinSpace))) {
        return;
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();

    CharSequence charSequence = this.getText();

    mSpanHolderList.clear();

    String[] words = this.getText().toString().split(" ");

    //Get spans within the string and adds the instance references into the
    //SpanHolderList to be applied once the justify process has been performed.

    SpannableString s = SpannableString.valueOf(charSequence);
    if ((charSequence instanceof SpannedString)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getText().length() - 1; i++) {
            CharacterStyle[] spans =
                    ((SpannedString) charSequence).getSpans(i, i + 1, CharacterStyle.class);
            if (spans != null && spans.length > 0) {
                for (CharacterStyle span : spans) {
                    int spaces =
                            charSequence.toString().substring(0, i).split(" ").length + charSequence.toString()
                                    .substring(0, i)
                                    .split(mThinSpace).length;

                    SpanHolder spanHolder =
                            SpanHolder.getNewInstance(spans, s.getSpanStart(span), s.getSpanEnd(span), spaces);
                    mStringBuilderCSequence.setLength(0);
                    for (int j = 0; j <= words.length - 1; j++) {
                        mStringBuilderCSequence.append(words[j]);
                        mStringBuilderCSequence.append(" ");
                        if (mStringBuilderCSequence.length() > i) {
                            if (words[j].trim().replace(mThinSpace, "").length() == 1) {
                                spanHolder.setWordHolderIndex(j);
                            } else {
                                spanHolder.setWordHolderIndex(j);
                                spanHolder.setTextChunkPadded(true);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    mSpanHolderList.add(spanHolder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mPaint = this.getPaint();
    mViewWidth = this.getMeasuredWidth() - (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());

    //This class won't justify the text if the TextView has wrap_content as width
    //And won't repeat the process of justify text if it's already done.
    //AND! won't justify the text if the view width is 0
    if (params.width != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            && mViewWidth > 0
            && words.length > 0
            && mJustifiedText.isEmpty()) {
        mThinSpaceWidth = mPaint.measureText(mThinSpace);
        mWhiteSpaceWidth = mPaint.measureText(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
            boolean containsNewLine = (words[i].contains("\n") || words[i].contains("\r"));
            if (containsNewLine) {
                String[] splitted = words[i].split("(?<=\\n)");
                for (String splitWord : splitted) {
                    processWord(splitWord, splitWord.contains("\n"));
                }
            } else {
                processWord(words[i], false);
            }
        }
        mJustifiedText += joinWords(mTemporalLine);
    }

    //Apply the extra spaces to the items of the SpanList that were added due
    //the justifying process.
    SpannableString spannableString = SpannableString.valueOf(mJustifiedText);

    for (SpanHolder sH : mSpanHolderList) {
        int spaceCount = 0, wordCount = 0;
        boolean isCountingWord = false;
        int j = 0;
        while (wordCount < (sH.getWordHolderIndex() + 1)) {
            if (mJustifiedText.charAt(j) == ' ' || mJustifiedText.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                spaceCount++;
                if (isCountingWord) {
                    wordCount++;
                }
                isCountingWord = false;
            } else {
                isCountingWord = true;
            }
            j++;
        }
        sH.setStart(
                sH.getStart() + spaceCount - sH.getCurrentSpaces() + (sH.isTextChunkPadded() ? 1 : 0));
        sH.setEnd(
                sH.getEnd() + spaceCount - sH.getCurrentSpaces() + (sH.isTextChunkPadded() ? 1 : 0));
    }
    //Applies spans on Justified String.
    for (SpanHolder sH : mSpanHolderList) {
        for (CharacterStyle cS : sH.getSpans())
            spannableString.setSpan(cS, sH.getStart(), sH.getEnd(), 0);
    }

    if (!mJustifiedText.isEmpty()) this.setText(spannableString);
}

private void processWord(String word, boolean containsNewLine) {
    if ((mSentenceWidth + mPaint.measureText(word)) < mViewWidth) {
        mTemporalLine.add(word);
        mWordsInThisSentence++;
        mTemporalLine.add(containsNewLine ? "" : " ");
        mSentenceWidth += mPaint.measureText(word) + mWhiteSpaceWidth;
        if (containsNewLine) {
            mJustifiedText += joinWords(mTemporalLine);
            resetLineValues();
        }
    } else {
        while (mSentenceWidth < mViewWidth) {
            mSentenceWidth += mThinSpaceWidth;
            if (mSentenceWidth < mViewWidth) mWhiteSpacesNeeded++;
        }

        if (mWordsInThisSentence > 1) {
            insertWhiteSpaces(mWhiteSpacesNeeded, mWordsInThisSentence, mTemporalLine);
        }
        mJustifiedText += joinWords(mTemporalLine);
        resetLineValues();

        if (containsNewLine) {
            mJustifiedText += word;
            mWordsInThisSentence = 0;
            return;
        }
        mTemporalLine.add(word);
        mWordsInThisSentence = 1;
        mTemporalLine.add(" ");
        mSentenceWidth += mPaint.measureText(word) + mWhiteSpaceWidth;
    }
}

//Method that resets the values of the actual line being processed
private void resetLineValues() {
    mTemporalLine.clear();
    mSentenceWidth = 0;
    mWhiteSpacesNeeded = 0;
    mWordsInThisSentence = 0;
}

//Function that joins the words of the ArrayList
private String joinWords(ArrayList<String> words) {
    sentence.setLength(0);
    for (String word : words) {
        sentence.append(word);
    }
    return sentence.toString();
}

//Method that inserts spaces into the words to make them fix perfectly in the width of the view. I know I'm a genius naming stuff :)
private void insertWhiteSpaces(int whiteSpacesNeeded, int wordsInThisSentence,
                               ArrayList<String> sentence) {

    if (whiteSpacesNeeded == 0) return;

    if (whiteSpacesNeeded == wordsInThisSentence) {
        for (int i = 1; i < sentence.size(); i += 2) {
            sentence.set(i, sentence.get(i) + mThinSpace);
        }
    } else if (whiteSpacesNeeded < wordsInThisSentence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < whiteSpacesNeeded; i++) {
            int randomPosition = getRandomEvenNumber(sentence.size() - 1);
            sentence.set(randomPosition, sentence.get(randomPosition) + mThinSpace);
        }
    } else if (whiteSpacesNeeded > wordsInThisSentence) {
        //I was using recursion to achieve this... but when you tried to watch the preview,
        //Android Studio couldn't show any preview because a StackOverflow happened.
        //So... it ended like this, with a wild while xD.
        while (whiteSpacesNeeded > wordsInThisSentence) {
            for (int i = 1; i < sentence.size() - 1; i += 2) {
                sentence.set(i, sentence.get(i) + mThinSpace);
            }
            whiteSpacesNeeded -= (wordsInThisSentence - 1);
        }
        if (whiteSpacesNeeded == 0) return;

        if (whiteSpacesNeeded == wordsInThisSentence) {
            for (int i = 1; i < sentence.size(); i += 2) {
                sentence.set(i, sentence.get(i) + mThinSpace);
            }
        } else if (whiteSpacesNeeded < wordsInThisSentence) {
            for (int i = 0; i < whiteSpacesNeeded; i++) {
                int randomPosition = getRandomEvenNumber(sentence.size() - 1);
                sentence.set(randomPosition, sentence.get(randomPosition) + mThinSpace);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Gets a random number, it's part of the algorithm... don't blame me.
private int getRandomEvenNumber(int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    return rand.nextInt((max)) & ~1;
}
```

}

```
public class SpanHolder {
private CharacterStyle[] spans;
private int start;
private int end;
private boolean textChunkPadded =false;
private int wordHolderIndex;
private int currentSpaces;
public SpanHolder(CharacterStyle[] spans, int start, int end, int spaces){
    this.setSpans(spans);
    this.setStart(start);
    this.setEnd(end);
    this.setCurrentSpaces(spaces);
}

public static SpanHolder getNewInstance(CharacterStyle[] spans, int start, int end, int spaces){
    return new SpanHolder(spans,start,end,spaces);
}


public boolean isTextChunkPadded() {
    return textChunkPadded;
}

public void setTextChunkPadded(boolean textChunkPadded) {
    this.textChunkPadded = textChunkPadded;
}

public int getWordHolderIndex() {
    return wordHolderIndex;
}

public void setWordHolderIndex(int wordHolderIndex) {
    this.wordHolderIndex = wordHolderIndex;
}

public CharacterStyle[] getSpans() {
    return spans;
}

public void setSpans(CharacterStyle[] spans) {
    this.spans = spans;
}

public int getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(int start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public int getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(int end) {
    this.end = end;
}

public int getCurrentSpaces() {
    return currentSpaces;
}

public void setCurrentSpaces(int currentSpaces) {
    this.currentSpaces = currentSpaces;
}
```

}

GOOD LUCK! (Y)

Comment: Here how to apply spannable to this textview

Comment: This is not working with Linkify.addLinks(), nor is it preserving my spans. It doesn't display them. Not sure what is wrong.